# how to compare two git branches on a declarative pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to compare two remote branches in my pipeline.

First, i tried the below command

```
sh(script: "git diff --name-only origin/branch1 origin/branch2", returnStdout: true)
```

But jenkins was not able to recognize the both branches. It only recognize the one provided by checkout scm.

I then tried to do a fetch

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'ID',
        usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
                    sh("git fetch origin branch 1")

}
```

but i got the below error:

fatal: could not read Username for 'HTTP_BITBUCKET_LINK': No such device or address

I also tried the sshagent, but i got the same error.

Could you please tell me if it's possible to compare two branches and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem.

I configured Jenkins to use checkout sources trough ssh on the behaviour section.

And i used the below code:

```
sshagent(credentials: [CREDENTIAL_GIT_SSH]) {

    sh "git fetch --no-tags origin '+refs/heads/BRANCHE1:refs/remotes/origin/BRANCHE1'"

            def gitDiff = sh(script: "git diff --name-only origin/BRANCHE1...origin/BRANCHE2", returnStdout: true).trim()

}
```